# What make is my BMX frame?

Tags: frames, bmx

I have a BMX forsale, but I would like to know what make the frame is so I can determine how much it is worth.
Does anyone recognise this symbol on the frame?[image: BMX - Photo of frame]

Thanks for your help
Jon

Answer (score 3):

The bike is one of the Haro Nyquist siganture models. There were a few different models and years so you would need to get the serial number and deciper from [BMX Museum Haro Serial Number Info](http://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=206889)

For instance if the S/N starts with R24W5.... it will be a 2005 Haro R24 Nyquist.