# please help me identify this bike, it is a haro bmx frame and i have the serial number

Tags: identify-this-bike

The serial number on my haro frame is RVW1K00270. it is a bmx frame, i wanted to try find out which model and year is it please?

Comment: I'd get in contact with Haro and ask them?

Comment: Do use the search functions of SE to find questions already asked and answers already provided.   http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/18066/what-make-is-my-bmx-frame/18069#18069  links to http://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=206889 which suggests yours is a 2001 Revo.    Voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

it should be a 2001-ish Revo because it starts with RV. This website may help:

http://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=206889